# Entity Framework 4 Databinding on WinForms ComboBoxes with Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, combobox, foreign-keys

I am using Entity Framework 4, I need to get WinForms to bind Customers and Quotes as a Master - Detail relationship.

I have a Quote table which I lay out as details view on a Windows Form.

The quote table has 3 foreign keys to the customer table. (fields CustomerId, SiteCustomerId, InvoiceCustomerId which all link to Id field in the Customer table).

On the form there are 3 Customer panels with the Customer Name fields in a ComboBox, and other Customer detail fields in textBoxes.

How do I wire up the combo boxes so that they display all the possible Customers in the drop down from the Customer table and have the correct Selected Value, and save to the correct CustomerId field in the Quote table.

My (bad) attempt:

```
     Context = new Entities();
        quoteBindingSource.DataSource = Context.Quote;
    customersBindingSource.DataSource = Context.Customers;

        comboBox1.DataSource = customersBindingSource;
                    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Customer";
                    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";

                    comboBox1.DataBindings.Clear();
                    comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", quoteBindingSource, "CustomerId");

comboBox9.DataSource = customersBindingSource;
            comboBox9.DisplayMember = "Customer";
            comboBox9.ValueMember = "Id";

            comboBox9.DataBindings.Clear();
            comboBox9.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", quoteBindingSource, "InvoiceCustomerId");

            comboBox6.DataSource = customersBindingSource;
            comboBox6.DisplayMember = "Customer";
            comboBox6.ValueMember = "Id";

            comboBox6.DataBindings.Clear();
            comboBox6.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", quoteBindingSource, "SiteCustomerId");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you for your WinForms project version:) Well it occurs, that either something is wrong or we may have discovered a kind of a bug. In situations like that it is usually safer to assume that we lack some kind of knowledge. The solution is simple yet weird: in every Combobox you do:

```
comboBox9.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", quoteBindingSource, "InvoiceCustomerId");
```

What you should do to improve the situation with values coming back to old ones is:

```
comboBox9.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedValue", quoteBindingSource, "InvoiceCustomerId",true));
```

Now there is a question. Why ? When you look at the IntelliSense hint for the Add method of the DataBindings collection you see sth. like this:

> Creates a System.Windows.Forms.Binding using the specified control property name, data source and data member, and adds it to the collection

Well in my humble opinion, after reading this description, the result of the two lines of code cited above should be pretty much the same. Why it is not ? Well let's hope it is only our lack of knowledge, otherwise it is a bug:)

Comment: That does indeed help. Thanks Tobias.

Comment: Heh, then sorry for your trouble with migrating it to WinForms... but remember... never enough training :)

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for all your help. Could I bother you again?

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for all your help. Could I bother you again? The app has changed a bit, but I have stripped it back again to a non DX quote only form. The problem arises when clicking Add New. The idea is to clear the Customer/Address fields for a new Quote. I can't seem to do this without resorting to the ClearAddressFields() method which is called at AddNew and BindingComplete. It is very flickery too when changing records. And also incorrectly clears fields when going back/forth through records from a New one. Could you pls take a look? Code is up at http://excelthoughts.com/code/QMv2.rar

Comment: Hi, I will be able to look at it in 1 day, lot of work tommorow and I have just read your message.

Comment: The issue is that when a Quote has a null value for CustomerId, the Name ComboBox is correctly empty because that control is bound to quoteBindingSource's CustomerId. The Address, Phone, Suburb controls are bound to customerBindingSource and are not updated as they still seem to be bound to whatever the previous customerBindingSource was and not to the null value.

Comment: I am 99% sure that ClearAddressFields() is a bad solution. But I am at a loss at how to make the Address/Suburb etc fields clear when CustomerId is null for the current Quote. This needs to happen for both a New Quote and on an existing Quotes.

Comment: Hello Andrew. I am terribly sorry but things at work has been pretty tough at work lately. Probably you have managed to solve the problem but I will explain it anyway. First thing is: looking at your data model you can see that there is no connection (NavigationProperty) between Customers and PostCodes, that is why State, Suburb and Postcode are not correctly bound to form's controls. A quick is to do: `if (!(quoteBindingSource.Current as Quote).CustomerId.HasValue)
                e.Binding.Control.Text = "";` in a method bound to BindingComplete event of Addr,Phone, etc. textboxes.

Comment: BindingComplete event for textBoxAddress's Binding only fires when 
the Customer changes. This does not happen on Add New Quote or when I move to a Quote with !CustomerId.HasValue
Is there something else I am missing?

void DoCustomersBinding()
{
var b = new Binding("Text", this.customersBindingSource, "Address", true);
 this.textBoxAddress.DataBindings.Add(b);
 b.BindingComplete += (s, e) => ClearFields(e);            
}

private void ClearFields(BindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
 Quote q = quoteBindingSource.Current as Quote;

 if (!q.CustomerId.HasValue)
 {
  e.Binding.Control.Text = "";
 }
}

Comment: No. I still haven't solved the issue. I appreciate the time you have taken to help Tobias

Comment: I have included the Postcodes as Navigation property in the Model, to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Well your approach is not that bad as you said. First thing: do you need this Clear() statement ? What is the purpose of using it here? The second thing is that you can try to change your code as follows and see if it helps:

```
quoteBindingSource.DataSource = Context.Quote;
customersBindingSource.DataSource = Context.Customers;
```

to

```
.......
List<Quote> quotes;
List<Customer> customers;
.....
quotes = Context.Quote.ToList();
customers = Context.Customers.ToList(); 
.....
quoteBindingSource.DataSource = quotes;
customersBindingSource.DataSource = customers;
```

and then in each ComboBox instead of:

```
comboBox6.DataSource = customersBindingSource;
```

you do:

```
comboBox6.DataSource = customers;
```

Also make sure that the foreign keys are really properly defined for the tables because otherwise you must use the navigation properties instead of referencing to keys while adding DataBinding to ComboBoxes. When it comes to saving, the context has a SaveChanges() method, look it up. Hope it helps.

I recommend Julie Lerman's book on EF4 (second edition) called [Programming Entity Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596807260)

Comment: Thanks Tobias. Glad I am on the right track. If I click on 1 combobox the display value is the same in all 3 comboboxes. If I then click the 2nd combo, all display values change to the 2nd combo value. Is having 3 foreign keys all pointing to the Id in the Customer table illegal?

Comment: By all means it is not illegal. My fault. Try adding a seperate BindingSource for 2 other ComboBoxes and set its DataSources as 2 other new Lists having the same content from Context as the first one, modify ComboBoxes DataSources and it should be fine.

Comment: The combo boxes are independent now. However when I change a value and then focus on another control the displayed value reverts back to what it was before.

Comment: Well it is hard to tell if you do not provide the code responsible for moving around the Quotes. I have used a sample database where there is one table with 2 foreign keys to one table and 2 foreign keys to another table, I wired up this main table's binding source to a binding navigator, and everything works just fine (appropriate values change when I move to another row in the main table, in your case Quota, and I can change the value in combos and they do not change back after selecting another one)

Comment: The code and db are at 
http://excelthoughts.com/code/QM%20-%202010.rar 
It is a 200KB file.

Comment: The content of the QuoteForm is pretty much what you have pasted here. I am more interested in the code responsible for moving around the quotes (logic for changing the values in combos for different quotes). I see that this logic is done in XtraForm1, but looking at the code, there is only initialization, the whole "magic" is done using designer and I cannot switch to design mode because you are using DevExpress controls in your project and I do not have them installed, if you can give me a project using standard VS controls, that would be perfect. Otherwise I am afraid I can't help you.

Comment: Will do that for you tonight hopefully. It is probably the DevExpress controls that are the issue

Comment: Thanks Tobias. I have uploaded a non DevExpress version now