# C# .net Combobox displays valuemember not displaymember when bound to dataset

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, combobox, valuemember

I'm trying to populate a combo box from a dataset, then bind it to a different data row.
The datarow contains a single customer records.
The dataset contains 1 table with title_id (an int) and title (the text description).

I set the value and display members, and the datasource of the combo box:

```
cbxTitle.ValueMember = "title_id";
cbxTitle.DisplayMember = "title";
cbxTitle.DataSource = dsTitles.Tables[0];
```

Next I set the data binding to the data row with the customers details:

```
cbxTitle.DataBindings.Add("Text", drCustomer.Table, "title_id");
```

When I run it, the combo box displays the number 2 (the value of title_id in the data row).

If I click it, it contains Mr, Mrs, Miss etc as i'd expect (Mr = 2)

What I can't figure out is how to get it to display 'Mr' instead of 2?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
cbxTitle.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", drCustomer.Table, "title_id");
```

Please refer to these links too:

[Entity Framework 4 Databinding on WinForms ComboBoxes with Foreign Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025880/entity-framework-4-databinding-on-winforms-comboboxes-with-foreign-keys)

[Why does the ComboBox.SelectedValue DataBinding context gets cleared when BindingList changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973682/why-does-the-combobox-selectedvalue-databinding-context-gets-cleared-when-bindin)

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much.  I knew my theory was right, and I couldn't see the problem even though it was staring me in the face!